# Drupal 7: Ajax Powered Multi-step Forms

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal-7, multi-step

In Drupal 7, I am currently working to develop a multi-step Ajax form with the following workflow:

1. The user selects an item from a dropdown (`<select />`)
2. A group of radio buttons appear on the page, based on the selection made above.
3. The user selects one of the radio buttons, which causes another set of radio buttons to appear and so-on.

The first two steps are easy, and I've found plenty of examples for firing an Ajax call based on a dropdown selection. Adding one or more steps, however, based on the radio buttons has proven pretty challenging for me.

I've been trying to use the information found at [this link on api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example--ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc/function/ajax_example_wizard/7), which promises to deliver exactly what I need - but have not been able to make it work.

I copied the form to my module and I added the "`ajax_example_wizard_callback`" function that simply returns the form: `return $form`. I'm not sure if this is right or not, but all I have gotten working is the first step (asking for my name). When I click "next step" it just loads the same page again (or perhaps it's loading nothing... I'm not sure).

Am I missing something? Has anyone been able to make this (example) work?

This seems like a very useful thing to me, having multi-step, Ajax powered forms, but I have not been able to find a lot of discussion about it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example--ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc/function/ajax_example_wizard/7 The sample perharps has buggy code. I've tried that no success too

Answer (score -4):

AJAX-enabled forms in Drupal 7 offer dynamic form behavior with no page reloads and are easy to create and manipulate. They are a simple extension of the Drupal Form API.

Comment: That's a really poor answer and is completely useless.